# Android Toggle Button - Background Color

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I'm trying to use a Toggle Button, supporting back to API 11. The problem is this standard Toggle Buttom seems to have a greyish background color, while I just want it to be white (like the background).

[image: Example picture]

I've been trying:

```
android:background="@color/white"
android:background="@null"
```

but then I also lose the indicator light, which I want to keep.
I've seen a few answers about changing the background color of the toggle button (creating own selector), but I seem to be losing the indicator light with those as well.

This is the relevant part of the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/event_bottom_sheet_attenders"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/state_list_people_person_bottom_sheet"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/state_list_people_person_bottom_sheet"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Attenders"
                android:textColor="@color/material_teal_500" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/event_bottom_sheet_toggle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/material_teal_500"
                android:textOff="Not going"
                android:textOn="Going" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, did you ever come to a solution for this? I tried the `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` option, but it removes the indicator line below.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider looking at different [android themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) for a start.

Choose a theme that is ideal for your liking or you can customize your own if you want something special.

From what you have described, you can try Android Light theme. Change your activity information as such:

```
  <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

P/s: Applying a theme also allows your app too look more consistent.

Comment: My activity is using a dark theme, which I would like to keep. The place where I'm displaying this, is in a bottom sheet dialog. Any way I could apply a theme to just that?

Comment: In that case, you have to create your custom drawable to set it as a background.

Comment: Hmm yeah, thought that as well. Do you have any idea how I can find the drawable normally used by the light theme, so I can pretty much just copy from there and tweak as needed?

Comment: I am not too sure about that, so sorry abt it

Comment: That's all right, thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: sure! let me know if it helps

Comment: @sihao I know I'm late but setting this as background `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` should work

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :-

```
ToggleButton Btn=new ToggleButton(this);// or get it from the layout by ToggleButton Btn=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.IDofButton);
    Btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked)
                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY);
            else buttonView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
```

Do it accordingly as you need.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: If I do this, I also lose the indicator light (the cyan bar at the bottom).